# back up a postgres db and restore on another computer

Tags: postgresql, backup, development-environment, restore

I've just purchased a new computer (mac OSX) and I want to continue developing using the same database I had on the old computer. I don't want it remotely done cause I dont want to keep the other computer on. I just want to copy the db and put it on this computer for development. I have a USB stick I can use but I'm not sure how to proceed. brew, rails, ruby, rvm, pg are all installed and configured.

Comment: have you tried pg_dump? The standard mode produces ascii. --schema-only and --data-only might prove useful (you need them both). You might need separate passes (of pg_dumpall) to dump users and tablespaces, if any.

Comment: I'm pretty new to programming. Can I just copy a file that hold the data on to a USB stick and paste into the corresponding file on the new computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pg_dumpall ?
To dump all databases:

```
$ pg_dumpall > db.out

To reload this database use, for example:

$ psql -f db.out postgres
```

I had to do it with -o option for the oids